# batch file deal with Ampersand (&) in folder name

Tags: batch-file, directory, ampersand

Batch file below:

```
@echo off
set filelocation=C:\Users\myself\Documents\This&That
cd %filelocation%
echo %filelocation%
pause
```

give the following output:

```
'That' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
 operable program or batch file.
 The system cannot find the path specified.
 C:\Users\myself\Documents\This
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Considering I cannot change the folder name, how do I handle the "&"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two changes.

1) The extended set syntax with quotes prefix the variable name and at the end of the content

2) delayed expansion to use the variable in a safe way

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "filelocation=C:\Users\myself\Documents\This&That"
cd !filelocation!
echo !filelocation!
```

Delayed expansiuon works like percent expansion, but it have to be enabled first with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then variables can expanded with exclamation marks `!variable!` and still with percents `%variable%`.

The advantage of the delayed expansion of variables is that the *expansion* is always safe.
But like the percent expansion, where you have to double percents when you need it as content, you have to escape exclamation marks with a caret when you use it as content.

```
set "var1=This is a percent %%"
set "var2=This is a percent ^!"
```

Comment: References on the difference between "!" and "%" are welcomed

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Powershell is just another Microsoft tool that is today _the future_ and tomorrow MS will introduce the next tool that will be _the future_ and then powershell is deprecated like all the other MS tools/technics. MS never builded anything reliable for 10 or 20 years, Something like that exists only in the linux world

Answer (score 1):

Unlike [Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351589/3439404), I don't think you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to use the variable in a safe way. Proper quotation could suffice for most use:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "filelocation=C:\Users\myself\Documents\This&That"
cd "%filelocation%"
echo "%filelocation%"
rem more examples:
dir /B "%filelocation%\*.doc"
cd
echo "%CD%"
md "%filelocation%\sub&folder"
set "otherlocation=%filelocation:&=!%" this gives expected result


SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "otherlocation=%filelocation:&=!%" this gives unexpected result
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Moreover, this is universal solution while delayed expansion could fail in case of `!` exclamation mark in processed string (e.g. last `set` command above).

Comment: You are right, you don't need delayed expansion, but to use a variable in a safe way is nearly impossible with percent expansion (or at least a challenge). Like your example shows, you used quotes in the `echo "%CD%"`, and it's get really nasty when there can be also quotes in the variable.

Comment: @jeb nasty or clean, I don't care: IMHO double quoting percent-expanded variables with `cmd` poisonous characters seems to be at least as safe as those unquoted and `!`-expanded in delayed expansion scope. Delayed expansion _could be useful_ (and sometimes _is necessary_) however its necessity is not the case here. BTW, volatile variable `%CD%` can't contain double quotes :)

Comment: @jeb for `echo` you can do `for %%a in ("%filelocation%") do echo %%~a`. Not pretty, but does work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

a. Quote the string; e.g:

```
set "filelocation=C:\Users\myself\Documents\This&That"
```

b. Use the escape character; e.g.:

```
set filelocation=C:\Users\myself\Documents\This^&That
```

To use that path with the `cd` command, enclose it in quotes.

```
cd /d "%filelocation%"
```

Comment: This is correct, but it solves only the first problem

Comment: `set filelocation=C:\Users\myself\Documents\This^&That` gives the same error.

Comment: No, it's the same error message,but now it's from the line `cd %filelocation%`. Before the error occurs at the `set file...`

Comment: Indeed non of the two ways actualy solves the problem

Comment: "non[e] of the two ways actually solves the problem" - just tested my commands and verified they work. Not sure what you're referring to. As JosefZ pointed out, since `&` is `cmd.exe`'s command separator character, you can prevent its interpretation by quoting or escaping.