# batch file for loop with spaces in dir name / (/f "delims=" not working)

Tags: batch-file, whitespace, directory

Running below

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "targetlocation=C:\Users\myself\Documents\FOLDER WITH BLANK SPACES\"
for %%f in (!targetlocation!*) do echo %%f
pause
```

prints:

```
C:\Users\myself\Documents\FOLDER
WITH
BLANK
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I tried to implements the following change, but it fails to run (see source below)

```
for f/ "delim=" %%f in (!targetlocation!*) do echo %%f
```

[batch file for loop with spaces in dir name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553040/batch-file-for-loop-with-spaces-in-dir-name)

Comment: Try `for %%f in ("!targetlocation!*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with :

```
set targetlocation="C:\Users\myself\Documents\FOLDER WITH BLANK SPACES\"
```

Comment: @SchaDee. I do need delayedexpansion for other reasons (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351455/batch-file-deal-with-ampersand-in-folder-name)

Comment: OK ! But that's not your problem, did you try my answer ?